# How to prove that the inequality $u^{2}-v\leq 0$ is convex

Tags: inequality, convex-analysis

Is it sufficient to show that the Hessian matrix is positive definite?
$$\mathbf{H} = \begin{bmatrix}2&0\\0&0\\\end{bmatrix}$$
I have a small question: it seems to me that we do nothing with the inequality, so it seems not really relevant in proving whether the inequality is convex or not? Or am I missing something?

Comment: What are you asking? Are you asking whether the region defined by $u^2 - v \le 0$ is convex?

Comment: Sorry, updated.

Comment: I think the point is that this matrix is the (constant) Hessian for the function $F(u, v) = u^2 - v$, and the region is a lower level set of the function. If you can show $F$ is a convex function, then the region is a convex set.